# How can use external js files into angular.json in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular6, angular-router, app-route

I have a side bar menu script file, in assets folder that I include into `index.html`. Whenever I refresh the `home/dashboard` child route the script will be working, If I'm redirected from the initial route `/` to `home/dashboard` the sidebar show/hidden button doesn't work (this logic is part of the script I mentioned) Once I refresh the page, the external scripts will work properly. Here is my routing module

```
 app.routing.module.ts

 const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
      //{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent,  },
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,
      children:[
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent,},
        { path: 'totalapproved', component: ApprovedComponent,},
        { path: 'campaign', component: CampaignmanagerComponent,},]}
    ]
```

Is there any way to add external assets script to angular.json file?

Comment: Share more details and state your question properly. Unable to understand what you want exactly.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand your problem exactly,but I think your problem is that y our external script will only execute on initial page load. So if you refresh the page, then navigate to a child route , thenthey will not work. This is normal behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You can add you external script and style in angular.json file like

```
"styles":[ 
"src/assets/css/style.css"
],
"scripts"[
"src/assests/js/script.js"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"styles":[ 
"/style.css"
],

"scripts"[
"src/script.js"
]
```

You can also add it to your index.html if you're using CDN.